# Record triggered flow not triggering

Tags: visual-workflow

I just converted a simple workflow rule (workflow with email alert) into a flow and when I am testing, it's not working. The flow doesn't even trigger. It keeps saying that the entry criteria are not met.
So I simplified the criteria to be as follows:
stage = closed lost
Owner id = Pooja

Action - send email to CG

Even after simplifying, the flow doesn't trigger.  It says that the entry criteria is not met.

For testing: I am testing with an opportunity where the stage is Closed lost and the ownerid = "Pooja"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks Pooja[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OwnerId` must be a valid Salesforce Id, so it cannot be "Pooja".
If it's the owner's name, you could create a Formula field (i.e. `Owner Name`) on Opportunity, then use it in the entry condition.
The formula could be something like `Owner.Username` (if you want to filter for the username) or `Owner.FirstName & " " & Owner.LastName` (if you want to filter for "Pooja Arora"). There is no need to add this field to the page layouts.

Most likely you would like to run this flow *Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements*

Comment: Thanks Ruben for clarifying.  I used the migrating tool to convert the workflow rule to Flow and started testing right away.  It makes total sense.  Will fix it now.